# How do you start a Dataflow template from a Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

From my workstation I can fire templated Dataflow jobs with the `gcloud dataflow jobs` command. The required authorization to insert a new job come from my workstation where I'm logged in.

On the Compute Engine instance I rely on it's service account. The one with `(number)-compute@`. Within the AIM section I enabled `Dataflow/Dataflow Admin`, `Dataflow/Dataflow Developer` and `Dataflow/Dataflow Worker` for this service account to be safe.
I even added `Cloud Dataflow Service Agent` when I came across that one.

Then I try to start a Dataflow from the command line but I get an error about insufficient authentication scopes: `ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

If I do a `gcloud config auth` and login with my personal account, of course, it works.
Somehow I'm missing the proper permissions to set to the applied service account.

Is there a guideline I missed? Can somebody please point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the instance does not setup access scope properly. To launches a job from a GCE VM, the VM must have compute.read-only, compute, or cloud-platform scope for the project.

The way to verify it is using the command "gcloud compute instances describe --zone=[zone][instance]" and look for "scopes".

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts) and this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298860/insufficient-authentication-scopes-error-using-google-api) may provide useful guidelines for you.