# Request had insufficient authentication scopes (Google Cloud Resource Manager)

Tags: angular, api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to make a Google Cloud Resource Manager Call in an Angular project and I'm using angular/fire to use Firebase services. So I use the auth method of angular/fire and authenticate with oAuth2 of google between popup user and return the credentials and tokens.

When I use the token to call the API sends me an Error:

```
"error":{"code":403,"message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

My call is below:

```
createProject(token): Observable<any>{


    const body = {
      "name": 'newAgent',
      "projectId": 'newAgent123',
      "labels": {
        "test": 'test'
      }
    }


    return this._http.post(`
      https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?
      access_token=${token}`,
      body
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to make sure that service account you're using for authentication has a proper access scope**.

It has to have [Datastore access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#associating_a_service_account_to_an_instance) `(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore)` to be able to talk to Firestore's API.
You can read more here [how Firestore API works](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/use-rest-api).

You can [set proper scopes for your service account using console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#console_1) in the VM details page.

**After you change the scopes it is required to restart the instance - otherwise they won't be applied.**

Similar case was also discussed on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298860/insufficient-authentication-scopes-error-using-google-api). It may be helpful.

Comment: If I understand, it need IAM permission credentials level to use ir, and maybe the firestore auth scope don't work for Cloud Resource Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to authenticate and get the rigth scopes:
FIRST: Create a oAuth popup:

```js
openPopup() 
  {
    const name = 'Authorization'
    const options = `width=${ 500 },height=${ 600 },left=${ 0 },top=${ 0 }`;
    const url = `
          https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
          client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&
          response_type=code&
          include_granted_scopes=true&
          scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&
          redirect_uri=http://localhost&
          access_type=offline`;

    return window.open(url, name, options);
  }
```

THEN Verify the code:

```js
authApi(): Observable<any>{

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })

    let body = `
        code=<RESPONSE_CODE>&
        client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&
        client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&
        grant_type=authorization_code&
        redirect_uri=http://localhost`;


    return this._http.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`,
    body, {headers: headers})
  }
```

BUT NOW, WHEN I TRY TO USE THE API sends me this error

```
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects: 0 Unknown Error"
```

BECAUSE I try to use the API with the next function

```js
createProject( token ): Observable<any>{


    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'
    })


    const body = {
      "name": 'newAgent',
      "projectId": 'newAgent123',
      "labels": {
        "test": 'test'
      }
    }


    return this._http.post(`https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects`,
      body, { headers: headers }
    )
  }
```