# Allow google cloud compute to access firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup a small vm on google cloud compute. I want it to be able to access my firestore database, but I cannot make it work.
I tried using the firebase-admin lib in the vm, but it is making a permission denied error. My firestore rules fine.
Do you know how to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298860/insufficient-authentication-scopes-error-using-google-api

Answer (score 2):

I created this community wiki from the comment of the OP, as mentioned the solution was found on the next [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302489/5495197).

It was required enable Cloud API access scope for the services on Google Cloud Console for VM instance [details](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances)

It's required to **stop** the instance in order to change API scope as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add `Cloud Datastore User` [IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant-single-role) to the service account used by the instance, and set `Cloud Datastore` [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) to `Enabled` on that instance.**

If your Firestore is hosted on a different GCP project than the one on which your Compute Instance is running, you will also need to add that service account to your Firestore's GCP project through IAM, and then give it that same role there.